# The Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\arctan(nx)}{1+(x-n)^{3}}}$ on $x \in [0, 10]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've stumbled upon this problem, while preparing to my exams. The problem is that I cannot understand which $M_n$ should I finally come to, trying to apply the Weierstrass M-test. I also couldn't have found similar-to questions here.
I made several attempts, stating that $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, \forall x\in E[0,10] : \arctan(nx) \leqslant nx$ or $\arctan(nx) \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$, but for some reason nothing works out for me. My best attempt for now was to state that the given $|u_n(x)| \leqslant \frac{\pi}{(n-x)^2}$, but the thing is that it is not true for all x in the given $E$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You first have a big issue with the denominator... Which vanishes for example when $x=0$ and $n=1$, $x= 1$ and $n=2$... So your function is not even defined on $[0,10]$.

Comment: When $x=0$ and $n=1$ the summand is not defined.

Comment: That is true, and that was also the thing that confused me, since in the book no comment is provided about these values, actually $\forall x \in E$, s.t. $x - n = -1$ the summand is not defined.. And i don't really know whether it's a sort of a 'trick question', where i just have to note that to say the sum is not even convergent, or something else..

Comment: @O.spectrum I don't know from which book this is coming from... At least can we say that the author is not great at proof reading what he writes. In an exam, I think that noticing this issue with the definition set is the first think to do to prove that you are looking precisely at the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n>10$ and $x\in[0,10]$, then$$1+(x-n)^3>1+(10-n)^3=1-(n-10)^3,$$and so$$|1+(x-n)^3|>(n-10)^3-1.$$Furthermore, $\arctan(nx)<\frac\pi2$. Therefore,$$\left|\frac{\arctan(nx)}{1+(x-n)^3}\right|<\frac{\pi/2}{(n-10)^3-1}.$$Since the series$$\sum_{n=11}^\infty\frac{\pi/2}{(n-10)^3-1},$$converges, then your series converges uniformly, by the Weierstrass $M$-test.